# How to remove/ignore a known host when trying to ssh without write access to the known-hosts file (or sudo)

Tags: linux, ssh

I’m a non-sudo user trying to ssh into another server. When I do, it complains that the host key and IP address for the host has changed according to the known_hosts file (and indeed it has). Unfortunately, I can’t change the known_hosts file, and using the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option disables password authentication.

Answer (score 0):

> I can’t change the `known_hosts` file

If you can copy it, so you can change the copy, then tell `ssh` to use the copy. The relevant options in `ssh_config` are:

> `GlobalKnownHostsFile`
> Specifies one or more files to use for the global host key database, separated by whitespace. The default is `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`, `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2`.
>
> `UserKnownHostsFile`
> Specifies one or more files to use for the user host key database, separated by whitespace. The default is `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, `~/.ssh/known_hosts2`.

<sup>([source](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#GlobalKnownHostsFile))</sup>

**But wait!** You said

> using the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option disables password authentication.

I think it's not the option that disables password authentication. It's the new server who doesn't allow it. This means any approach that lets you actually connect to this particular server will not work along with password authentication. It doesn't matter if you circumvent the obsolete `known_hosts` file or get it fixed; the server itself is configured not to allow passwords.

If you're sure it's the *right* server then ask the server admin to allow passwords (or maybe they will provide some other way of authentication). Ask your local admin to update the `known_hosts` file.